# Passing variables to Data for Jquery Plot

Tags: javascript, jquery, plot

I have a Jquery.Flot.Pie chart and when I pass directly numbers to Data it works (like this), and also with only one slice.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {


    var ord = $("#MyUserInfoBoxControl_txtOrd").val();        
    var lav = $("#MyUserInfoBoxControl_txtLav").val();
    var pro = $("#MyUserInfoBoxControl_txtPro").val();
    var con = $("#MyUserInfoBoxControl_txtCon").val();
    var ins = $("#MyUserInfoBoxControl_txtIns").val();

    alert(ord + "," + lav + "," + pro + "," + con + "," + ins);

    var data = [
        { label: "INS", data: 0, color: "#FFFFFF" },
        { label: "LAV", data: 0, color: "#4572A7" },
        { label: "PRO", data: 0, color: "#80699B" },
        { label: "CON", data: 0, color: "#AA4643" },
        { label: "ORD", data: 100, color: "#3D96AE"}
    ];

    alert(data[0].toString())

    $.plot($("#Grafico"), data, {
        series: {
            pie: {
                show: true,
                threshold: 0,
                tilt: 1

            }
        },
        legend: {
            show: false
        }
    });
});
```

Instead, When I try to pass variables to data array it doen't work anymore (the alert it's Ok, so data are Right) I've tried also to use parseFloat() but nothing to do:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {


    var ord = $("#MyUserInfoBoxControl_txtOrd").val();        
    var lav = $("#MyUserInfoBoxControl_txtLav").val();
    var pro = $("#MyUserInfoBoxControl_txtPro").val();
    var con = $("#MyUserInfoBoxControl_txtCon").val();
    var ins = $("#MyUserInfoBoxControl_txtIns").val();

    alert(ord + "," + lav + "," + pro + "," + con + "," + ins);

    var data = [
        { label: "INS", data: ins, color: "#FFFFFF" },
        { label: "LAV", data: lav, color: "#4572A7" },
        { label: "PRO", data: pro, color: "#80699B" },
        { label: "CON", data: con, color: "#AA4643" },
        { label: "ORD", data: ord, color: "#3D96AE"}
    ];

    alert(data[0].toString())

    $.plot($("#Grafico"), data, {
        series: {
            pie: {
                show: true,
                threshold: 0,
                tilt: 1

            }
        },
        legend: {
            show: false
        }
    });
});
```

Can someone Help me? Thanks!

Comment: Cast vars to integer and pass it then checkout the answers below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `.val()` method returns values as `string` you need to cast them to `integer`:

```
var ord = +$("#MyUserInfoBoxControl_txtOrd").val();        
var lav = +$("#MyUserInfoBoxControl_txtLav").val();
var pro = +$("#MyUserInfoBoxControl_txtPro").val();
var con = +$("#MyUserInfoBoxControl_txtCon").val();
var ins = +$("#MyUserInfoBoxControl_txtIns").val();
```

prefix the `+` to cast them to `integer` or instead of prefix `+` you can use `parseInt()` method too.

Answer (score 1):

Use like below

`{ label: "INS", data: parseInt(ins), color: "#FFFFFF" },`

Follow the same of other variables

[DEMO](http://fiddle.jshell.net/FbMh3/5/)